# Can not run node script when using Gitlab CI ERR: ': No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab

I want to run a script with Gitlab CI/CD, I have tested and it work well on local but when I run it on Gitlab, I got the error: `': No such file or directory`, this look very strange to me. Here is the output I got from Gitlab

```
$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root           189 Dec 17 02:42 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root            38 Dec 11 01:45 ..
drwxrwxrwx    7 root     root           143 Dec 17 02:42 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           867 Dec 17 02:42 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           123 Dec 14 02:38 .gitmodules
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1284 Dec 16 02:12 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           173 Dec 17 02:26 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root            60 Dec 17 02:27 be
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root            35 Dec 16 02:28 fe
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           205 Dec 17 02:26 config.json
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root            82 Dec 17 02:42 scripts
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          1209 Dec 17 02:42 test
$ ls -la ./test
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          1209 Dec 17 02:42 ./test
$ git diff @~1 -- config.json | grep -A4 be | ./test
': No such file or directory
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Note:

- The command `git diff @~1 -- config.json | grep -A4 be` is success and it give a string output
- The content of file `./test` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
```

What's wrong with it?
[image]

Comment: The error `"': No such file or directory"` does not appear related to `test`. What is `@~1` supposed to expand to?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `git diff @~1` will check diff for current version (HEAD) versus previous version (the most recent commit)

Comment: Okay, that make sense, though bash will also try and expand unquoted `~` to `$HOME`., e.g. `echo $HOME` or `echo ~` both expand to the same thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Definitely!